# What's the problem in my code? c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms Login and Main form. Initially, the Login form will be displayed and when the user is authenticated, the Main form will be displayed and the Login form will be closed.

It's kinda working, but I have to click the btnLogin (a Button in the Login form) twice to close the Login form and show the Main form.

Here's my code.

**Program.cs** (Login form)

```
namespace Login
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Login fLogin = new Login();
            if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.Run(new Main());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login form**

```
namespace Login
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // initially btnLogin has a DialogResult property set to None
            Authenticate();
        }

        private void Authenticate()
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data source=d:/BIMS.sdf");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Properties.Resources.CheckIfUserExists, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());

            SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            bool hasRow = dr.Read();
            if (hasRow)
            {
                btnLogin.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where do you think I'm doing it wrong? 
Thanks....

Comment: Have you done some debugging?

Comment: yes sir... it seems my auth code gets the user

Comment: i think it's because the btnLogin DialogResult property is set to none. it will be set to `OK` only if the user is authenticated. So, the user must click the button twice to be able to close the dialog... what should I do?

Comment: if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.Run(new Main());
            }          In this use flogin.Dispose(); after Application.Run(new Main());

Answer (score 3):

just change

```
if (hasRow)
{
  // btnLogin.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
     this.close();
}
```

Comment: what is the remaining problem?

Comment: Don't call Close(), setting the form's DialogResult property is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should just call `Form.Close()` in your button event handler, when you want to close the form (after setting desired `DialogResult`).

As far as I know, it is not going to happen automagically.

I have never done it any other way, and this approach has always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

> namespace Login
>
> {
>
> static class Program
>
> {
>          /// 
>          /// The main entry point for the application.
>         ///
>
> ```
>    [STAThread]
>    static void Main()
>    {
>        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
>        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
>        Application.Run(new Login());
>    }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

>

> namespace Login
>   {
>      public partial class Login : Form
>      {
>          public Login()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>           }

```
    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // initially btnLogin has a DialogResult property set to None
        Authenticate();
    }

    private void Authenticate()
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data source=d:/BIMS.sdf");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Properties.Resources.CheckIfUserExists, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());

        SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        bool hasRow = dr.Read();
        if (hasRow)
        {
            Main formmain = new Main();
            formmain.Show();
            this.Dispose(); // U can also use this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _@Ankush, @yonan:_ There are three problems here in the way how the `Login` and `Main` forms interact. **1)** It seems logically wrong that the `Login` form spawns the `Main` form at all; IMO, this violates the Single Responsibility Principle. `Main` should be shown from the `Program` class, right after the `Login` form has closed & returned. **2)** The `Main` form should be modal (`ShowDialog`), not modeless (`ShowDialog`). Otherwise the program will terminate too soon. **3)** The `Login` form shouldn't `Dispose` itself. Instead, wrap `new Login()` in a `using` block, over in `Program.Main`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with your Authenticate() most likely. Can you remove that code and simply have

```
private void Authenticate()
{
   btnLogin.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

This will tell you if if the problem is with the authentication code or with the gui.

If it's with your authen code it is possible that you need do a little more to access the database(check and see if you are connected, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the prev post, might be an issue with Authenticate method...
May be it is taking a bit longer to access db..
Below code would help us know if the Authenticate has completed processing...

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      btnLogin.Enabled = false; 

      // initially btnLogin has a DialogResult property set to None
      Authenticate();
      // better place call to Authenticate in try catch blocks
      // to prevent btnLogin in a disabled state forever if Authenticate fails with
      // an exception ...
      // also if an exception occurs show that in a message box

      btnLogin.Enabled = true;
}
```

And in Main, once the user has been authenticated, close the Login form

```
 Login fLogin = new Login();
            if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fLogin.Close();
                Application.Run(new Main());
            }
```